# When does a man allowed to shave his head?

Tags: sharia

Is it permissible for men in Islam to shave their heads?

Actually I got to know that its not allowed for men to shave their heads except certain days like Hajj, Umrah, Aqeeqa and/or for certain disease.

When does a man allowed to shave his head?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For men it is allowed to shave the head and considered as an act of worship when

- Hajj
- Umrah ([Al-Quran-48:27](http://quran.com/48/27))
- Shaving the child’s head on the seventh day after birth.

  > Ali ibn Abi Taalib (may Allaah be pleased with him) who said:
  >   The Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him)
  >   offered a sheep as ‘aqeeqah for al-Hasan, and said: ‘O Faatimah, shave
  >   his head and give the weight of his hair in silver in charity.
  >   (Al-Tirmidhi, 1439).
- The kaafir when he becomes a Muslim

> The Prophet(peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) commanded a
>   kaafir man who had become Muslim, “Shave off the hair of kufr and get
>   circumcised.” (Abu Dawood 356)

It is **not allowed** to shave the head after father or any other relative's death or for showing the symbol of rejection of worldly adornments.

But, one could be allowed to shave the head because of any medical reasons like remedy for disease, or to prevent lice and so on.

> Abu Dawood narrated (4195) that the Prophet (peace and blessings of
>   Allaah be upon him) saw a child who had part of his head shaved and
>   not other parts. He said: “Shave it all or leave it all.” (Classed as
>   saheeh by al-Albaani in Saheeh Abi Dawood, 3535). Al-Nawawi (may
>   Allaah have mercy on him) said: “This clearly shows that it is
>   permissible to shave the head, and it cannot be interpreted in any
>   other way.” (Sharh Muslim).

Using these two hadeeths to show that it is permissible to shave the head for **no reason** is a matter.

For more details, see [this](http://islamqa.info/en/14051).